# How to cast overloaded free function to resolve overload conflict?

Tags: c++

Say you have 2 free functions:

```
void do_something(dog d);
void do_something(cat c);
```

No say you want to pass these functions to a templated function:

```
template <typename DoSomethingFunc>
void do_something_template(DoSomethingFunc func);
```

What would be the preferred way to call `do_something_template` in a manner that avoids overload resolution conflicts? Would it be casting?

Comment: What do_something_template does?  I suspect that it needs an  animal argument, and it should select and call appropriate function on this animal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cast or use a local function pointer variable.

```
void (*p)(dog) = do_something;
do_something_template(p);
```

---

```
do_something_template(static_cast<void(*)(cat)>(do_something));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just cast it:

```
struct dog {};
struct cat {};

void do_something(dog d);
void do_something(cat c);

template <typename DoSomethingFunc>
void do_something_template(DoSomethingFunc func);

void f() {
  do_something_template((void(*)(dog))do_something);
  do_something_template(static_cast<void(*)(cat)>(do_something));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it using C++ casts - in this case `static_cast` is most appropriate.

```
do_something_template(
    static_cast<void(*)(dog)>(do_something)
);
```